# Mirror a repo using libgit2sharp (or other c# library)

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I want to clone a repo, and I want the clone to have all the tags from the original.
I can do this manually like so

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/{org}/{SourceProjectName}.git
$ cd {SourceProjectName}.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/{org}/{ProjectName}
```

It seems libgit2sharp is the best way to do this, but if there's a better way let me know.

I don't understand how to do it with libgit2sharp
It seems I have to do a clone, then somehow copy refs 
Then I have to iterate over all of those refs and stage them all... then commit?
I started working on doing all this but it feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel...

Where I looked so far:

- https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/577
- https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/#repositories_clone_mirror
  (I didn't understand this well enough to translate to c#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the ideal solution but this seems to do the trick:

```
private void DuplicateGitHubRepo()
{
    var clonePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Temp-" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".git");
    var co = new CloneOptions
    {
        CredentialsProvider = GetGitCredentials()
    };

    Repository.Clone(SourceProjectUrl+".git", clonePath, co);
    using (var repo = new Repository(clonePath))
    {
        repo.Network.Remotes.Update("origin", x => x.Url = TargetProjectUrl);
        var options = new PushOptions
        {
            CredentialsProvider = GetGitCredentials()
        };
        repo.Network.Push(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"],repo.Refs.Select(x=>x.CanonicalName),options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linked issue had the solution.

A git mirror clone is just a clone with a remote origin set to `+refs/*:refs/*`

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository(Repository.Init(@"path\to\local.git", true)))
{
    var remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", "https://github.com/{org}/{SourceProjectName}.git", "+refs/*:refs/*");
    repo.Network.Fetch(remote /* anything for report progress */);
}
```

The RemoteCollection.Add() method looks like the following:
`public virtual Remote Add(string name, string url, string fetchRefSpec)`

Basically that third parameter is where you need to set that special refspec.

Comment: I think that's only the clone part of the solution, and not the push part which appears to the more involved.

Comment: Also... the example does not work in the latest version of libgit2sharp (so I'm trying to grok how to rewrite it) ... but I found using the command line that it did not matter if I did a clone --bare or a clone --mirror as long as I used the --mirror argument when I push then I get the tags ( so confused :-D )